# Quiero llamar los datos que se ingresen en un JTextField desde una clase main, ¿se puede?

Tags: java, netbeans

En mi programa quisiera llamar a un **JFrame** llamado *frame1* desde una clase `main`. En ese **JFrame** tengo 2 `jTextField2`. Quiero ingresar valores en esos `jTextField2` y después usar estos valores en la clase `main`, pero me dice que los `jTextField2` están en privado y no puedo acceder a ellos, ¿qué puedo hacer?

[image: este es el JFrame con los 2 jTextField2]

[image: Esto es lo que me sale al querer usar los valores de los jtext field]

Comment: Yo opino que si se puede, solamente tienes que saber programar lo suficiente an Java y [tag:java-swing].

Answer (score 0):

Crea dentro de la clase donde tienes el atributo `jTextField2` un método getter que lo retorne y de este modo podrás acceder a él desde otra clase.

```
public JTextField getJTextField2() {
    return jTextField2;
}
```

Luego podrás hacer algo como esto:

```
ahorro[i] = Integer.parseInt(frame1.getJTextField2().getText());
```

Comment: un setter seria mejor. puesto lo que se desea es Dar el valor al "UI" tiene mas sentido desde la perspetiva de lo que hacer.
ademas existe un posible problema con esta solucion. se asume que (por la razon que sea) los datos son accesados desde `main()` existe la posibilidad que `Main()` no esta ejecuntadose en el mismo hilo dado a que Swing deverian ejecutarse en `Event Dispatch Thread` y el compartir variables de esta forma puede causar problemas [ver: Main Thread vs. UI Thread in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156949/main-thread-vs-ui-thread-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Si los estás haciendo con algún IDE, la solución es sencilla.
Te muestro un ejemplo utilizando el IDE NetBeans.
Selecciona el componente al que quieres acceder, en este caso, el JTextfield, da click derecho y selecciona propiedades/properties, dirígete a la pestaña Code, selecciona Variable Modifiers y ahí notarás que aparece como private, cambia esa propiedad a public.
Si lo estás haciendo por línea de código, cuando crear el objeto JTextField, tiene que quedar declarado de la siguiente manera:

```
public javax.swing.JTextField ejemplo;
ejemplo = new javax.swing.JTextField();
```

Una vez hecho esto, tienes que crear un objeto de un clase frame1 en tu clase principal (donde quieres traer los datos) algo así:

```
frame1 frm = new frame1();
int edad = Integer.parseInt(frm.jTextField2.getText());
```